# Change the view text of footer itemView of recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

Hi I have a condition where I have to add different viewType with text

`show more` or `loading...`

at the bottom of the recyclerview

I have successfully added the footer view with show more and also I have added the listener on this footer item view for loading more data, here everything works fine. Since I have swipe refresh layout as a parent for recyclerview I show enable swiperefresh progress on loading and disable swiperefresh progress while loading is complete. Now what I need is whenever I click on the `show more` view type which is a footer attached to the recycler view I want the text to be changed with `loading...` and when the loading is completed the text should be changed to `show more` again.

Here is my adapter class

```
class MyTransactionAdapter(private val context: Context?,
                       private val transactionList: List<TransactionHistoryResponse>,
                       private val transactionListener: MyTransactionListener) : Filterable,
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private var viewTypeList: Int = 0
private var viewTypeFooter: Int = 1


private var transactionListFiltered = transactionList

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return if (viewType == viewTypeList) {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_my_transaction, parent, false)
        ListViewHolder(view)
    } else {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_footer_so_more, parent, false)
        FooterViewHolder(view)
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val myTransaction = transactionListFiltered[position]
    if (holder is ListViewHolder) {
        holder.bind(myTransaction, transactionListener)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return transactionListFiltered.size
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (position == transactionList.lastIndex) {
        viewTypeFooter
    } else {
        viewTypeList
    }
}

inner class FooterViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.apply {
            btnShowMore.setOnClickListener {
                transactionListener.onLoadMoreClicked()
            }
        }
    }

    fun enableShowMore(enable: Boolean) {
        if(enable){
            itemView.btnShowMore.text = "show more"

        }else{
            itemView.btnShowMore.text = "loading..."

        }
    }
}
inner class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private lateinit var mTransactionStatus: TransactionStatus
    fun bind(myTransaction: TransactionHistoryResponse, transactionListener: MyTransactionListener){
        //logic to populate data on views
       }
    }
 }
```

**And here is the fragment's function where I do the loading stuff**

`This function is being called for fetching data from remote`

```
private fun getTransactionHistory() {
    swipeContainer.enableDisableSwipeRefresh(true)
    enableShowMore(false)
  //logic to load web data and hide show swiperefresh
  //when load is success call this function enableShowMore(true)
  //when load is failed call this function enableShowMore(false)
}

@Synchronized
private fun enableShowMore(enable: Boolean) {
    val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(transactionList.size)
    if (viewHolder is MyTransactionAdapter.FooterViewHolder) {
        viewHolder.enableShowMore(enable)
    }
}
```

//this is the implemented method when footer view is clicked
    override fun onLoadMoreClicked() {
        fetchTransactionListFromServer()
    }
Is there anything I need to do with this approach because users are able to click the footer multiple at a time without letting the app to load the remote data.
Hope you have understood the situation if not let me know. Thanks in advance

Here is the screenshot what I have achieved
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try disabling the footer view button once the user clicks on it?

```
fun enableShowMore(enable: Boolean) {
        if( enable ) {
            itemView.btnShowMore.text = "show more"
        } else {
            itemView.btnShowMore.text = "loading..."
        }
        itemView.btnShowMore.isEnabled = enable
    }
```

Update :

```
//In the adapter
mIsFooterEnabled = false

//In the View holder 
fun enableShowMore() {
  if( mIsFooterEnabled ) {
      itemView.btnShowMore.text = "show more"    
  } else {
      itemView.btnShowMore.text = "loading..."  
  }
  itemView.btnShowMore.isEnabled = mIsFooterEnabled
}

//In your activity / fragment
private fun enableShowMore(enable: Boolean) {
    adapter.mIsFooterEnabled = enable
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: This is the question I asked. I am not able to disable the footer view button when I clicked on this view.

Comment: itemView.btnShowMore.isEnabled = enable, did you add this line and check? Is it still not getting disabled?

Comment: main thing is the enableShowMore() function is never called

Comment: Check if the viewholder is null at the point, if it is returning null, you'll need an alternate way to resolve this. I'll post a different solution if it's null.

Comment: ViewHolder is not null. The viewholder called is instance of ListViewHolder but I required the instanceo f FooterViewHolder. By the mean time I have done with alternate ways. but in this case I have added null at last to the list while data is fetched successfully and checked the item in the adapter as ` val da = transactionList[position]
        return if (da == null) {
            viewTypeFooter
        } else {
            viewTypeList

        }`

Comment: sure I will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to put your function code inside **enableShowMore()** in **onBindViewHolder()** or set **holder.bind** for **FooterViewHolder** and put code inside binder function.

Let me know if it is useful or not.

Comment: @Vagish I just provided suggestion to fix it. If it does not work then i can provide more information along with code. **Ram Mandal** let me know if it does not work.