# How to prevent textview from breaking words?

Tags: android, textview

The text inside the textview breaks with hyphen on different devices. It works fine on most devices. How can I stop the text from breaking? I'm using different dimens.

This is my code for the textbox,

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:lines="2"
     android:text="Medical History"
     android:textSize="@dimen/text_label" />
```

These are the values of text_label:

```
<dimen name="text_label">16sp</dimen> 
<dimen name="text_label">19.2sp</dimen> //hdpi
<dimen name="text_label">22.4sp</dimen> //xhdpi
<dimen name="text_label">25.6sp</dimen> //xxhdpi
<dimen name="text_label">28.8sp</dimen> //xxxhdpi
```

What I want:

Medical
History

What I have:

Medical Hi-
 story

What I want:

Medication

What I have:

Medica-
 tion

Comment: `What I want:` did you mean `What I  have:`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add this in your TextView's XML

```
 android:breakStrategy="simple"
```

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354898/change-the-view-text-of-footer-itemview-of-recyclerview)